# Open webpage when program is opened?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to find a way in Windows how I can open a webpage when an application is ran.  For example:

When application.exe is opened, open www.google.com in the default internet browser

Comment: not clear with your question,plz mention details

Comment: Not sure how else to explain this.  I need to find a way that when application.exe is opened, www.google.com is also opened in the default browser

Comment: Is it your application? Or is the trigger some other executable? Do you know any programming language?

Comment: Are you working on an application or what ? please be clear

Comment: This is an existing application. Lets just say for arguments sake, when iTunes.exe is opened, Google opens in the default system browser

Comment: I know exactly what the OP is asking... gosh I knew the answer years ago...

Comment: whether u need to open an explorer with google as default with .exe ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not mention any programming language I will just assument you have access to the WinAPI.

You need to periodically check the list of running processes. For example with [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If your "trigger" application is found, call [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like this:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "http://www.google.com", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

This will open a webpage in the default brower.

Have some state variable to make sure, it's executed once per startup of the application.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a batch script to start any number of programs at once, and relink the specified shortcuts to said batch script. There was a way, I'm *sure*, where you could add a registry key to somewhere that contained the program that was run and the program to run. Google is being no help though so maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

if its not related to any programming language then just make google as your default browser and open webpage (IE or firefox) through .exe.